# How to get pixel at position in base64 PNG

Tags: node.js, image, selenium

How to get the pixel color at a coordinate from a base64 png image data?

```
driver.takeScreenshot().then(
    function(image, err) {
        require('fs').writeFile('out.png', image, 'base64', function(err) {
           console.log(err)
        });
       getPixelColorAt(40, 500, image)
    }
);

function getPixelColorAt(x,y,data) {
//should return an Hexadecimal value
}
```

Comment: Node doesn't provide a way to directly encode/decode a PNG image. You'll have to use a library like pngjs.

Comment: @FlorentB. assuming I use a library, can I convert the base64 data into pixel array directly or do I have to save the png file and parse it again?

Comment: The method `takeScreenshot` returns a base64 string. There's no need to save it on your drive if you convert it to a Buffer with `Buffer.from(base64string, 'base64')`.

Comment: @FlorentB.thanks. Your comment helped a lot